# Match documents against wildcard / regex stored in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have documents in elastic search (5.0) with text fields containing regex or wildcards for example `"https://*.twitter.com"`. How can I query against these documents with strings like `"https://www.twitter.com"`? I know of wildcard/regex queries but in those wildcards/regexes were always present in the query and not vice versa (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Added mapping for reference,

```
                    "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: please add your mapping

Comment: thanks, @AlkisKalogeris updated the question with the mapping, nothing fancy though, it is just a dynamically added text field. I didn't anticipate it to have wildcards/regexes in future